# Counter-examples for the quasi-unipotence of monodromy over an annulus?

Tags: hodge-theory

The question is inspired by Carnahan's comment in the following MO question

[What is the intuition for $\mathbb{Q}^{ab}$ having cohomological dimension $1$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97051/what-is-the-intuition-for-mathbbqab-having-cohomological-dimension-1?rq=1)

Precisely, Borel proved (not Grothendieck, I think, who proved the arithmetic version) that, when **S** is a punctured disk, and *H* is a variation of polarized Hodge structures on **S**, then the monodromy operator is quasi-unipotent. Are there any counter-examples when **S** is a complex annulus? If yes, any examples of geometric origin? Namely *f: X ---> **S*** is a holomorphic family of projective manifolds ... .

To get started, what is the universal covering (as a complex manifold) of an annulus *a < |z| < b* ?

Thank you.

Comment: By complex manifold, do you mean Riemann surface? In which case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-surfaces#Parabolic_Riemann_surfaces

Comment: I get confused: the universal covering of the punctured disk, which is a special case of an annulus, is the hyperbolic disk rather than the complex plane, right? So, the link you showed me doesn't seem quite right...

Comment: Yes: map the disk to the left half-plane and then exponentiate

Comment: Shenghao, the universal cover of the annulus is the still the upper half plane. As far as I can tell, the argument [Schmid, Variations of Hodge ..., p 230] still applies, but I'm too lazy to check carefully. (As an aside, geometric examples would extend all the way to the punctured disk.)

Comment: @ Donu: Thanks for the clarification; so the info on wiki needs to be fixed. Do you mean that it seems unlikely to have geometric examples over annuli? @ ulrich: Thanks for the comment. But I cannot see the consequence of the situation you pictured. Would you like to extend it to an answer and explain some details?

Comment: Shenghao, I haven't looked at the wiki, but if it says the opposite then it's not right. My second and third sentences weren't well thought out, ulrich is right. A product of (quasi-)unipotent matrices need not be quasi-unipotent...

Comment: ah I see what you mean. But still, it's better to have a real example where this happens indeed. I don't have much feeling for the holomorphic category, but it seems unlikely that in one family, these q-unip. matrices can be arbitrarily chosen. Any results in this direction?

Comment: I deleted an earlier comment by mistake. The content was that there is no reason to expect quasi-unipotence over an annulus since the VHS could extend to a disk with several singular fibres "inside" the annulus.

Comment: Dear Shenghao, You can move any three points in $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ to any other three points.  So change coords. on $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ so that $0,$ $1$, are moved into some small disk, and $\infty$ is moved outside a larger disk containing it, and consider the annulus between these two disks.  Consider the family $y^2 = x(x-1)(x- \lambda)$, which has singular points at $0$, $1$, and $\infty$, but now in the new coords., so that its singular points corresponding to $0$ and $1$ are inside the small disk.  The  monodromy matrices around $0$ and $1$ are  ...

Comment: ... $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and their product is $\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which is not quasi-unipotent.  (This gives a concrete instance of the general example of @ulrich. Also, when I write $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$, I of course mean the family of *projective* curves, and I am considering the monodromy action on $H^1$.) Regards, Matthew

Comment: Dear Matthew, I get confused: isn't the product of the monodromy matrices at 0 and 1 equal to the inverse of that at infty? Thanks.